# notify-send can't display popups

Tags: kubuntu, libnotify, notify-send

I have a problem with notify-send. It's clearly visible that it tries to show the popups, but they only come up about 20 pixels at the bottom of the screen. Then when it times out I see the whole popup blinking and disappearing as if the message crashed.

Easily reproducible by "notify-send test"

However if run the same with sudo, the popup works but is in a different location and totally different style ( up in the top right corner with blue background and rounded corners ) as it's not even using the same notify system ? The non sudo location is in the bottom right with grey background and non rounded corners.

Any ideas ?

I am on Kubuntu 14.04, but the same problem existed also before I upgraded.